# C++ Linux basic_string::_M_construct null not valid error during runtime

Tags: c++, linux, runtime

This is C++ on Linux. I'm getting the error during runtime, and I've narrowed down the code to be here, which is a constructor of a custom object. What I do is create a new thread and pass a function to it. In this function, I call the constructor like this:

```
ColorNinja cn(gameData->difficulty);
```

`gameData` is a struct that's also passed to the thread, where `difficulty` is an `int` member variable.

I don't fully understand the error or exactly what's causing it. Does anyone have any insight?

Here is the constructor. I can provide more code if necessary.

```cpp
ColorNinja::ColorNinja(int difficulty) {
    // create the engine that will generate random numbers
    random_device rand;
    mt19937 engine(rand());

    int randomNumber = 0;

    // possible colors that can be present on the randomly-generated game board
    vector<string> possibleColors = {"red", "blue", "yellow", "green"};

    uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution2(0, possibleColors.size());

    // build the game board by choosing and inserting random colors
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        randomNumber = distribution2(engine);
        gameBoard.push_back(possibleColors[randomNumber]);
    }

    // print the game board
    cout << "gameBoard.size(): " << gameBoard.size() << endl;
    for (string s : gameBoard) {
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `possibleColors.size()-1` when initializing `distribution2`:

```cpp
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution2(0, possibleColors.size()-1);
```

The two constructor parameters for `std::uniform_int_distribution` are the *minimum* and *maximum* values to be generated. By using `possibleColors.size()` as the maximum value, you allow the generator to return an index that may be out of bounds of the array. Had you used `possibleColors.at(randomNumber)`, you would have gotten a `std::out_of_range` error thrown if that actually happened.  Using `possibleColors[randomNumber]` does not perform any bounds checking, so it will happily take an invalid index, and then your code will have **undefined behavior**.  So it is important that you initialize your generator to produce only valid indexes.

---

On a side note: since `possibleColors` is a fixed array, consider using `std::array` instead of `std::vector` for it:

```cpp
#include <array>
std::array<string, 4> possibleColors{"red", "blue", "yellow", "green"};
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it! Thank you so much!